# ggplot : shading missing data in time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, missing-data

I am plotting time series in ggplot, at different sites.
For each site, I have missing data (i.e. days not monitored, NA), that are different from zeros in my response variable.
These missing dates do not appear in my dataset, which only contains on-effort rows.

Is there a way in ggplot to shade the off-effort areas, knowing that the missing dates are not the same at each site (i.e. vary per facet of the plot) or should I find a go-around method by creating rows OFF-effort ?

Here is the code I use for the plot:

```
ggplot(data = t, aes(x = Date, y = Y, col=NA)) + geom_col(size=1, alpha=.7, linetype=0, col="black")+ylim(c(0,24))+ facet_wrap(~Site, nrow=3)+ xlab("")+ylab("y")+theme_minimal()+ 
theme(
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.text.x = element_blank()
)
```

[image]

And here is a reproducible example of the dataset:

```
t <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18535, 18536, 18537, 18538, 
18539, 18540, 18541, 18542, 18543, 18544, 18545, 18546, 18547, 
18548, 18549, 18550, 18551, 18552, 18553, 18554, 18555, 18556, 
18557, 18558, 18559, 18561, 18562, 18563, 18564, 18565, 18566, 
18567, 18568, 18569, 18570, 18571, 18572, 18573, 18574, 18575, 
18576, 18577, 18578, 18579, 18580, 18581, 18582, 18583, 18584, 
18585, 18586, 18587, 18588, 18589, 18590, 18591, 18592, 18593, 
18594, 18595, 18596, 18597, 18598, 18599, 18600, 18601, 18602, 
18603, 18604, 18605, 18606, 18607, 18608, 18609, 18610, 18611, 
18612, 18613, 18614, 18615, 18616, 18617, 18618, 18619, 18620, 
18621, 18622, 18623, 18624, 18625, 18626, 18627, 18628, 18629, 
18630, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 18637, 18638, 
18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 18643, 18644, 18645, 18646, 18647, 
18648, 18649, 18650, 18651, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 18656, 
18657, 18658, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18664, 18771, 
18774, 18776, 18777, 18778, 18779, 18780, 18782, 18783, 18797, 
18798, 18799, 18801, 18814, 18815, 18816, 18817, 18818, 18819, 
18820, 18821, 18822, 18823, 18824, 18825, 18826, 18827, 18828, 
18829, 18830, 18831, 18832, 18833, 18834, 18835, 18836, 18837, 
18838, 18839, 18840, 18841, 18842, 18843, 18844, 18845, 18846, 
18847, 18848, 18849, 18850, 18851, 18852, 18853, 18854, 18855, 
18856, 18857, 18858, 18859, 18860, 18861, 18862, 18863, 18864, 
18865, 18866, 18867, 18868, 18869, 18870, 18871, 18872, 18873, 
18874, 18875, 18876, 18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18881, 18882, 
18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 18888, 18889, 18890, 18891, 
18892, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
18536, 18537, 18538, 18539, 18540, 18541, 18542, 18543, 18544, 
18545, 18546, 18547, 18548, 18549, 18550, 18551, 18552, 18553, 
18554, 18555, 18556, 18557, 18558, 18559, 18561, 18562, 18563, 
18564, 18565, 18566, 18567, 18568, 18569, 18570, 18571, 18572, 
18573, 18574, 18575, 18576, 18577, 18578, 18579, 18580, 18581, 
18582, 18583, 18584, 18585, 18586, 18587, 18588, 18589, 18590, 
18591, 18592, 18594, 18595, 18596, 18597, 18598, 18599, 18600, 
18601, 18602, 18603, 18604, 18605, 18606, 18607, 18608, 18609, 
18610, 18611, 18612, 18613, 18614, 18615, 18616, 18617, 18618, 
18619, 18620, 18621, 18622, 18623, 18624, 18625, 18626, 18627, 
18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 
18637, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 18643, 18644, 18645, 
18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18650, 18651, 18652, 18653, 18654, 
18655, 18656, 18657, 18658, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 
18664, 18665, 18666, 18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18671, 18672, 
18673, 18674, 18675, 18676, 18677, 18678, 18679, 18680, 18681, 
18682, 18683, 18684, 18686, 18687, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 
18692, 18693, 18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18699, 18700, 
18701, 18702, 18703, 18704, 18705, 18706, 18707, 18708, 18709, 
18710, 18711, 18712, 18713, 18714, 18714, 18715, 18716, 18717, 
18718, 18719, 18720, 18721, 18722, 18723, 18724, 18725, 18726, 
18727, 18728, 18730, 18731, 18732, 18733, 18734, 18735, 18736, 
18737, 18738, 18739, 18740, 18741, 18742, 18743, 18745, 18746, 
18747, 18748, 18749, 18750, 18751, 18752, 18753, 18754, 18755, 
18756, 18757, 18758, 18759, 18760, 18761, 18762, 18763, 18764, 
18765, 18766, 18767, 18768, 18769, 18770, 18771, 18772, 18773, 
18774, 18776, 18777, 18778, 18779, 18780, 18781, 18782, 18783, 
18784, 18785, 18786, 18787, 18788, 18789, 18790, 18791, 18792, 
18793, 18794, 18795, 18796, 18797, 18798, 18799, 18800, 18802, 
18804, 18805, 18806, 18807, 18808, 18809, 18810, 18811, 18812, 
18813, 18814, 18815, 18816, 18817, 18818, 18819, 18821, 18822, 
18823, 18824, 18825, 18826, 18827, 18828, 18829, 18830, 18831, 
18832, 18833, 18834, 18835, 18836, 18837, 18838, 18839, 18840, 
18841, 18842, 18843, 18844, 18845, 18846, 18847, 18848, 18849, 
18850, 18851, 18852, 18853, 18854, 18855, 18856, 18857, 18858, 
18859, 18860, 18862, 18863, 18864, 18865, 18866, 18867, 18868, 
18869, 18870, 18871, 18872, 18873, 18874, 18875, 18876, 18877, 
18878, 18879, 18880, 18881, 18882, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 
18887, 18888, 18889, 18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18895, 
18896, 18897, 18537, 18538, 18539, 18540, 18541, 18542, 18543, 
18544, 18545, 18546, 18547, 18548, 18549, 18550, 18551, 18552, 
18553, 18554, 18555, 18556, 18557, 18558, 18559, 18561, 18562, 
18563, 18564, 18565, 18566, 18567, 18568, 18569, 18570, 18571, 
18572, 18573, 18574, 18575, 18576, 18577, 18578, 18579, 18580, 
18581, 18582, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 18692, 18693, 18694, 
18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18699, 18700, 18701, 18702, 18703, 
18704, 18705, 18706, 18707, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 
18713, 18714, 18714, 18715, 18716, 18717, 18718, 18719, 18720, 
18721, 18722, 18723, 18724, 18725, 18726, 18727, 18728, 18729, 
18730, 18731, 18732, 18733, 18734, 18735, 18736, 18737, 18738, 
18739, 18740, 18741, 18742, 18743, 18744, 18745, 18841, 18842, 
18843, 18844, 18845, 18846, 18847, 18848, 18849, 18850, 18851, 
18852, 18853, 18854, 18855, 18856, 18857, 18858, 18859, 18860, 
18861, 18862, 18863, 18864, 18865, 18866, 18867, 18868, 18869, 
18870, 18871, 18872, 18873, 18874, 18875, 18876, 18877, 18878, 
18879, 18880, 18881, 18882), class = "Date"), Y = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 
161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 
205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 
227L, 228L, 229L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 
601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 
612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 
623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 
634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 
645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 
656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 
667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 
678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 
689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 
700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 708L, 709L, 710L, 
711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 718L, 719L, 720L, 721L, 
722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 731L, 732L, 
733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 
744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 754L, 
755L, 756L, 757L, 758L, 759L, 760L, 761L, 762L, 763L, 764L, 765L, 
766L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 772L, 773L, 774L, 775L, 776L, 
777L, 778L, 779L, 780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 786L, 787L, 
788L, 789L, 790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 797L, 798L, 
799L, 800L, 801L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 805L, 806L, 807L, 808L, 809L, 
810L, 811L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 815L, 816L, 817L, 818L, 819L, 820L, 
821L, 822L, 823L, 824L, 825L, 826L, 827L, 828L, 829L, 830L, 831L, 
832L, 833L, 834L, 835L, 836L, 837L, 838L, 839L, 840L, 841L, 842L, 
843L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 847L, 848L, 849L, 850L, 851L, 852L, 853L, 
854L, 855L, 856L, 857L, 858L, 859L, 860L, 861L, 862L, 863L, 864L, 
865L, 866L, 867L, 868L, 869L, 870L, 871L, 872L, 873L, 874L, 875L, 
876L, 877L, 878L, 879L, 880L, 881L, 882L, 883L, 884L, 885L, 886L, 
887L, 888L, 889L, 890L, 891L, 892L, 893L, 894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 
898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 905L, 906L, 907L, 908L, 
909L, 910L, 911L, 912L, 913L, 914L, 915L, 916L, 917L, 918L, 919L, 
920L, 921L, 922L, 923L, 924L, 925L, 926L, 927L, 928L, 929L, 930L, 
931L, 932L, 933L, 934L, 935L, 936L, 937L, 938L, 939L, 940L, 941L, 
942L, 943L, 944L, 945L, 1304L, 1305L, 1306L, 1307L, 1308L, 1309L, 
1310L, 1311L, 1312L, 1313L, 1314L, 1315L, 1316L, 1317L, 1318L, 
1319L, 1320L, 1321L, 1322L, 1323L, 1324L, 1325L, 1326L, 1327L, 
1328L, 1329L, 1330L, 1331L, 1332L, 1333L, 1334L, 1335L, 1336L, 
1337L, 1338L, 1339L, 1340L, 1341L, 1342L, 1343L, 1344L, 1345L, 
1346L, 1347L, 1348L, 1349L, 1350L, 1351L, 1352L, 1353L, 1354L, 
1355L, 1356L, 1357L, 1358L, 1359L, 1360L, 1361L, 1362L, 1363L, 
1364L, 1365L, 1366L, 1367L, 1368L, 1369L, 1370L, 1371L, 1372L, 
1373L, 1374L, 1375L, 1376L, 1377L, 1378L, 1379L, 1380L, 1381L, 
1382L, 1383L, 1384L, 1385L, 1386L, 1387L, 1388L, 1389L, 1390L, 
1391L, 1392L, 1393L, 1394L, 1395L, 1396L, 1397L, 1398L, 1399L, 
1400L, 1401L, 1402L, 1403L, 1404L, 1405L, 1406L, 1407L, 1408L, 
1409L, 1410L, 1411L, 1412L, 1413L, 1414L, 1415L, 1416L, 1417L, 
1418L, 1419L, 1420L, 1421L, 1422L, 1423L, 1424L, 1425L, 1426L, 
1427L, 1428L, 1429L, 1430L, 1431L, 1432L, 1433L, 1434L, 1435L, 
1436L, 1437L, 1438L, 1439L, 1440L, 1441L, 1442L, 1443L, 1444L, 
1445L, 1446L, 1447L, 1448L, 1449L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `scales="free"` in your `facet_wrap` function like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = t, aes(x = Date, y = Y, col=NA)) + 
  geom_col(size=1, alpha=.7, linetype=0, col="black")+ylim(c(0,24))+ 
  facet_wrap(~Site, nrow=3, scales = "free")+ xlab("")+ylab("y")+theme_minimal()+  
  theme( strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank() )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for flagging the "free" scale option, I didn't know of that one! Not exactly what I was looking for since I want to indicate the missing time clearly on the plot, but will definitely be useful at some point :)